# Proceed code after executing function PHP

Tags: php, function, return

I have data on my site a user can edit via a form. So If the page is opened the user will see the form filled whith his personal data. and when updated and he pushes the submit button I`ll call a function.

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    company_change($_SESSION['user_name']);     

    } ?>
<HTML>
(...) <-- form is here
</HTML>
```

after this function is processed I'll receive the return from the function, but the script is not proceed any further. (the regular HTML part)

So my question is. If I direct to a function from a IF statement, and let update some records. How can i make sure the script is executed further after completion of the function logic.

Do i miss a trigger in te IF statement or at the END of the function i call?

Hope someone can help?

Comment: Are you sure the code isn't failing with some kind of error?  Unless you explicitly end the response or direct control away from the code somehow, it will continue to process the code.

Comment: Since the HTML code is after the condition and not wrapped in `else` or something like that, the HTML code should appear. You might have a bug in the function that stops the pages from continuing to load the HTML part. Do you get any errors or can access your server's errors_log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don`t believe this but I had a "}" to much.

So the answer on this questions is: Use an IDE with auto-syntax correction/checking.

(I now use ShiftEdeit.net but you have much more)

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php and http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php), functions come back after they are called, even if you call them from an IF statement.

If your execution flow is not coming back from the function, there may be some reasons :

1. Something is happening in the function itself, for example, an unhandled exception been thrown.
2. The function internally jumps to another script or function where it is not returning from

Paste more of your code to take a better look.